# Создать один массив объектов из двух. C++

Tags: c++, массивы, конструктор, инициализация

Допустим у меня есть два массива по 5 объектов класса *Obj*. Я хочу поместить эти объекты из разных массивов в один результирующий, размерностью 10 элементов. Как правильно выделить под него память? Если я напишу вот так:

`Obj* result_arr = new Obj[10];`

или вот так

`Obj result_array[10];`

а затем цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result_arr[i] = arr1[i];
    result_arr[i + 5] = arr2[i];
}
```

то получится так, что у меня 10 раз вызовется конструктор класса Obj, если такой есть, при этом созданные объекты не будут никак использоваться. А если его нет, то вообще будет ошибка компиляции.
Единственное что мне пришло в голову это написать вот так

```
Obj* result_arr = malloc(sizeof(Obj) * 10);
```

но это же колхоз. Как то можно сделать это красиво в С++ стиле? И как vector справляется с подобной задачей? Ведь он добавляет элементы в уже зарезервированную область памяти.

Comment: У вас в любом случае будет 10 вызовов конструктора. Даже если вы будете использовать placement new. Разве что делать `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду конструкторов копирования? Да, в любом случае будет 10 вызовов конструкторов копирования либо 10 раз будет вызвана операция присвоения. Но при создании массива, будет ещё +10 вызовов, причём объекты, которые создадутся этими конструкторами не будут нигде использоваться.

Comment: вектор пользуется стандартным распределителем, а последный всеравно использует  malloc  для выделения памяти

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть как вектор выполняет метод `emplace`.

Comment: Могу, но для этого мне придётся создавать отдельный вопрос: "Где найти исходный код вектора?")

Comment: Если вы используете MSVS, то можно просто пройти по методу. Метод шаблонный, так что не скрыт в недрах компилятора. Правой кнопкой по методу и перейти к реализации.

Comment: Спасибо, как и сказал AR Hovsepyan, вектор использует malloc для выделения памяти, но хотелось бы всё таки узнать, нет ли другого "более красивого" решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готового решения для такого специального случая, как "инициализировать массив из нескольких отдельных диапазонов", нет. Так что в вашем случае остается лишь выделение "сырой" памяти с последующим `std::uninitialized_copy`

```
void *raw = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(Obj), sizeof(Obj) * 10);
Obj *arr = static_cast<Obj *>(raw);
std::uninitialized_copy_n(arr1, 5, arr);
std::uninitialized_copy_n(arr2, 5, arr + 5);
```